# Show that the following set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$ using CSB

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We have to show that the following set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$ using [CSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) (Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem).

$\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}\mid x^2+y^2=1 \}$

I think that these are the two functions:

$f:(x,y)\to \Bbb{R} \\f(x)=x,\\f(y)=y $

$g:\Bbb{R}\to (x,y)\\ g(x)=\cos(x),\\g(y)=\sin(y)$

Is this correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your definition of $f$ makes no sense. It's supposed to be a function of two variables, yet you feed it one variable at a time. A better choice might be $f(x,y)=y/x$, but then you have to do something different when $x=0$. Hint: does it matter what you do in that case? Also, your notation is off: It should be $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: In addition to what @Harald said, you could also have noticed that there are multiple coordinates with the same $x$ or $y$ coordinate on a circle, so your current choice of functions are not injective.

Comment: It isn't correct. Call $X$ the set (the unit circle); you must find an injective map $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ and an injective map $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to X$.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I misremembered the theorem. Looking at it, you are looking for *injective* functions in each direction, not *surjective* ones, as I had thought. (Does the corresponding theorem with surjective functions have a name too?)

Comment: @Harald: The corresponding theorem with surjective functions is independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$ but follows from $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: @Brian: I didn't know that, or possibly (likely?) I have known but forgot. Anyhow, I suppose it doesn't really have any name(s) attached to it, then?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, Right, it doesn't really matter for cardinality. We can write it like this then $f(x,y)=\frac{y}{x+1}$ ?

egreg, This is what I was trying to do here. Shouldn't it be a two variable functions ?

901301, yeah I see what you mean, that's for the f function there are 2 points for every x,y.

Comment: @Harald: I don’t know of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding an injective function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to X$, where $X$ is your set is easy: just remember the formulas for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ in terms of $\tan(x/2)$

> Set$$g(t)=\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$$

For an injective map $f\colon X\to \mathbb{R}$, observe that any point on the unit circle determines an angle.

Alternatively, observe that only two points of $X$ have the same $x$-coordinate

> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}x & \text{if $y>0$}\\x+100 & \text{if $y<0$}\\1 &\text{if $x=1$ and $y=0$}\\-1&\text{if $x=-1$ and $y=0$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Isn't $g(x)=(\cos (2\pi x),\sin (2\pi x))$ good enough instead of tan ? As for $f$, you mean we can do some sort of a y/x or tan(y/x) ? I also don't quite get how you got to that set.

Comment: @GinKin You want an *injective* map and your $g$ isn't. For $f$ it's essentially $\arctan(y/x)$, but with some corrections.

Comment: But isn't the revolution of cos and sin: $2\pi$ and they both go from 1 to -1 ?

The correction are probably: $arectan(\frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}})$ but I still don't get how you did you get to these terms...

Comment: x+100 ? How does that not cause any overlap ? Please explain. Your $g$ also. Sorry for not understanding...

Comment: @GinKin Why not $100$? If $(x,y)\in X$, then $-1\le x\le 1$, so surely $100$ is enough to avoid overlapping; use $3$ if you prefer. As for $g$: it's injective, isn't it?

Comment: Right, I see. About g, it is I just don't understand how you found these terms for x and y: $(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2})$. Are they simply known functions that go between -1 and 1 ?

Comment: @GinKin $t\mapsto\tan(t/2)$ is injective; then $\sin t=\frac{2\tan(t/2)}{1+\tan^2(t/2)}$ and $\cos t=\frac{1-\tan^2(t/2)}{1+\tan^2(t/2)}$. It's a well known parametrization of the unit circle.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** There is no continuous bijection between the two sets. Find a bijection from the unit circle to $[0,2\pi)$, and an injection from $\Bbb R$ into $[0,2\pi)$.

Also, when you define a function $g\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ you don't write $g(x)=\cos x$ and $g(y)=\sin y$. You should write $g(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$ instead. Similarly when defining $f\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, you should define $f(x,y)=z$ rather than writing $f(x)=x$ and $f(y)=y$.

Both functions that you have defined are meaningless expressions.

Comment: So one is $g(x)=(\cos (2\pi x),\sin (2\pi x))$ and the other is $f(x)=(|x2\pi|,-|x2\pi|)$ ? this $f$ is probably wrong again because it doesn't cover half of the circle.

Comment: GinKin, how can $f$ defined like this be a function from the circle into $\Bbb R$?

Comment: It doesn't, I thought that maybe if you copy the circle but no it's wrong.

Comment: Asaf, if you have a different solution than egreg, can you share it please ?

Comment: @GinKin: Note that $\iota(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is a bijection between the circle and $[0,2\pi)$. In particular, its inverse is an injection into $\Bbb R$; in the other direction find an injection from $\Bbb R$ into the interval $(0,1)$, or use the fact that such injection exists if you already proved that.

Comment: What about the function $f(x)=(x,\sqrt{1-x^2}$), could it work too ?

Comment: @kuhaku: Probably.